# how to add a list of object into another list

Tags: java, netbeans

i have an object of PesananDealer. It contain these variables.

```
private String idDealer;
private int[] motor = new int[4];
public PesananDealer() {
    }

    public PesananDealer(String idDealer, int[] motor) {
        this.idDealer = idDealer;
        this.motor = motor;
    }    

    public String getIdDealer() {
        return idDealer;
    }

    public void setIdDealer(String idDealer) {
        this.idDealer = idDealer;
    }

    public int[] getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(int[] motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }
```

I also have an object of Truck. It contain these variables.

```
public int ID;
public List<PesananDealer> listPesananDealer = new ArrayList<PesananDealer>();
public int kapasitas;
public String[] rute;
public Truck() {
}

public Truck(int ID, List<PesananDealer> listPesananDealer, int kapasitas) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.listPesananDealer = listPesananDealer;
    this.kapasitas = kapasitas;
}
public int biaya;

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String[] getRute() {
    return rute;
}

public void setRute(String[] rute) {
    this.rute = rute;
}

public List<PesananDealer> getListPesananDealer() {
    return listPesananDealer;
}

public void setListPesananDealer(List<PesananDealer> listPesananDealer) {
    this.listPesananDealer = listPesananDealer;
}

public void addPesanan(PesananDealer a) {
    listPesananDealer.add(a);
}

public int getKapasitas() {
    return kapasitas;
}

public void setKapasitas(int kapasitas) {
    this.kapasitas = kapasitas;
}

public int getBiaya() {
    return biaya;
}

public void setBiaya(int biaya) {
    this.biaya = biaya;
}
```

And now i want to make list of truck and insert it with data.

```
List<PesananDealer> list = new ArrayList<PesananDealer>() {
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dealer.length; i++) {
                    add(new PesananDealer(dealer[i], arrays[i]));
                }
            }
        };

List<Truck> list2 = new ArrayList<Truck>(){
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    add(new Truck(i,list,kapasitas[i]));
                }
            }
        };
```

can i add the list into list2 by doing it like that? 
How can i print list of the truck and all of it's data?

all of my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrays = {{3, 4, 5, 6},
                          {22, 12, 2, 2},
                          {1, 1, 3, 5},
                          {6, 5, 2, 1},
                          {14, 2, 4, 2}};
        String[] dealer = {"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        String [] rute = new String [10];
        int [] kapasitas = {34, 32, 36, 32,30};
        List<PesananDealer> list = new ArrayList<PesananDealer>() {
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dealer.length; i++) {
                    add(new PesananDealer(dealer[i], arrays[i]));
                }
            }
        };

        List<Truck> list2 = new ArrayList<Truck>(){
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    add(new Truck(i,list,kapasitas[i]));
                }
            }
        };

        for (Truck listTruck : list2) {
            System.out.println("Mobil ke "+listTruck.getID()+" memiliki kapasitas "+listTruck.getKapasitas());
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(listTruck.listPesananDealer.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "can i add the list into list2 by doing it like that?" <- You are not adding a List to the List, but you are passing a List<PesananDealer> to the Truck constructor. Wether or not you can do that depends of course of the Truck class has an constructor defined that accepts those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

So, how I understand, you've been asking if it works out to add `list` to `list2` and if `list` will be initialised. Am I right? So yes, you could put it in that way, because your code initialiser will be put to constructor by a compiler. Variables are initialised in order they declared in code, so `list` will be initialised when it's put in `list2`. But be aware you use the same `list` in each `Track`, so if `Track` changes `list`, it will be changed in every `Track`

Comment: i already edit my question by adding the whole code that i made. can i do it like that? because i already initialized the 'list' and 'list2' and i want to print the output all of my list.

Comment: Yes, you can. But gosh, that style... It isn't a good decision to use public members in classes - you should hide implementation of classes. Naming of members - write it English. `listTruck.listPesananDealer.get(i)` it's lame: `listTruck.listPesananDealer` is list, so use `for` like you did before for `list2`. I'd hide the `listPesananDealer` list (as all other members) as `private` and implement `Iterable`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html for `Truck` and I'd gave access to the list by iterator